# A bluetooth speaker that does not feature a connection sound

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking for a bluetooth speaker that does not feature a connection-sound. All I have sampled so far do something along the line of *beeep* or *Connection established* or *Connected*

I want one that *may* give a sound when pairing for the first time, and it *may* also indicate connection loss by other means (display, LEDs) - but it **must not make a sound when reconnecting after connection loss or when turning on to connect**.

If the connection sound can be deactivated (for ever), or set to silence (i.e. maybe one can set own soundfiles, then i would set a silent file) that is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t comment, so I thought I will just write an answer.

I think it will be hard to find a device, where you can make does kind of changes. That´s because those kind of systems do not offer much additional configuration options.

This is why I thought instantly of an Open-Hardware project. I directly found one and it seems you have here a couple of good options. The question would be now, when you would be interested of something like that or when you would want to buy a finished product. I have seen also some pre-build things (where say they´re opensource). Of course you can also build your own system from scratch, there´re a lot of tutorials and instructions online.

Maybe it´s worth a try?

Comment: would you be so kind as to share the open hardware projects adress?

Comment: Sure! I watched a time ago this diy project video from diy-perks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a43LXqRwQC8
I found this (sadly doesn´t get delivered anymore) in the internet: https://www.crowdsupply.com/blueshift/helium
I bet you find a little more out over Helium when you do research.

Comment: The first link btw. does contain a sound while connecting via bluetooth. But I´m very confident, that you can manipulate or erase this sound. :)